# Serializing object separation of concern

Tags: c#, .net

So here is a very basic question. I want to send / receive packages to an embedded device. The packages are binary serialized. So I want full control of the serialization, the endian-ness and the order of properties in the serialized data.

The most basic example would look like this. Of course, in reality, there will probably an `IPackage` interface etc. But it's not relevant to this example.

```
class MyPackage
{
    public int PackageId { get; set; }
    public float SomeValue { get; set; }

    public void Serialize(BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(PackageId);
        writer.Write(SomeValue);
    }

    public void Deserialize(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        PackageId = reader.ReadInt32();
        SomeValue = reader.ReadSingle();
    }
}
```

So every time I make a new package, I would implement the serialize and deserialize methods. This will work, but theory tells me I should separate the concerns. Serializing data isn't a concern this object should be handling. For example, what if we want to convert to another format? Then two more methods are required per package type.

So something like this would be better:

```
class MyPackage
{
    public int PackageId { get; set; }
    public float SomeValue { get; set; }
}

class MyBinaryPackageSerializer
{
    void Serialize(MyPackage package, BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(package.PackageId);
        writer.Write(package.SomeValue);
    }

    MyPackage Deserialize(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        var result = new MyPackage();
        result.PackageId = reader.ReadInt32();
        result.SomeValue = reader.ReadSingle();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now my concerns are separated, and I still have full control over the order and endian-ness of the serial data. But this would require 2 classes per package type. Also, it's prone to errors when properties get added but are forgotten in the serializer. This could also be seen as a good thing, because when a property is added, it should also be added to the embedded side of things acting as an extra failsafe to not just blindly modify the packages.

I could go loop through the properties using reflection and using attributes to determine the order, but the attributes will be specific to the serializer. If another serializer is later used, the attributes might be ignored or other attributes might be required. Also, I have read that reflection isn't good for performance.

Another option would be to use a visitor. In this case, all packages would accept a visitor and give pass the properties to the visitor. But now part of the code moves back to the Package. But it has the advantage of being able to create multiple visitors.

I think the visitor is the best option, any suggestions or things to keep in mind?

Comment: there is no single right or wrong answer here; you'd have to figure out *what works best for you*, given your unique constraints and requirements

Comment: _"The packages are binary serialized."_ - I second Marc and want to add I am doubtful you will be happy with that particular choice.

Comment: I would recommend using an existing protocol if you can. That will mean giving up some control, but hopefully the protocol authors have spent a lot of time thinking about all the possible problems that can occur. If that is not possible I would pick the visitor-approach, and be very thorough with unit tests and backward compatibility checks. Consider using records for your packages, the automatic equality comparer may make unit test simpler to write.

Comment: Options which may or may not work for you: 1) Google GRPC, 2).Make your MyPackage class and other data classes like it inherit off a base class which has Serialize and Deserialize methods which should be overridden..  Suggestion, have a private SerializeOrDeserialize() method in each class which takes a BinaryWriter/Reader and a Bool for isSerialize/isDeserialize.  That keeps properties all in one method and is easier to see that the same set of properties is processed and in the right order.  The public Serialize and Deserialize methods would call the private SerializeOrDeserialize method.